# How to postpone SONAR analysis in Jenkins to be the last operation in the post-build actions?

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins

I have an `Ant-based` project which I am deploying using `Jenkins`. If I add '`Add standalone SONAR`' analysis from the '`Add build steps`' option, it works fine but takes a long time. The problem is that there is a `post-build custom step` which deploys the build on the server. Since Sonar analysis takes a long time, `deployment has to wait till its complete`. Can I somehow postpone the SONAR analysis to after the deployment has been done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why no do the sonar analysis in a child jenkins job?

Answer (score 0):

You can also run Sonar as a POST build step after the deployment step.

Comment: That's if the project is Maven-built.. it seems because the options are quite Maven specific then (in Advanced).. there is no way to specify the sonar properties there directly